# Simulated Chrome SSL Errors

Tags: google-chrome, ssl

I'm trying to find out how chrome detects all types of certificates such as "expired", "self signed", "SHA 1 & expires next week", "SHA 1 & expires in 2020".

I remember seeing a site that showed all this information with subdomains with examples but I can't find it. Does anyone know this website or how I can find all the SSL rules that determine if Chrome shows the URL bar as green, normal or red?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://badssl.com is the go-to source for such tests :)

Comment: Amazing! Spent hours searching for this. Will mark as answer when it allows me :)